# react-router in browser. "hashHistory is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router

I am trying to use React-router in browser without using NPM

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/XjAmAg?editors=0011

I have added

```
let Router = window.ReactRouter;
let RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
let Route = Router.Route;
let DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
```

as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957868/how-to-use-reactrouter-cdn-way-without-npm-require).

But still, I receive this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hashHistory is not defined

Any idea how to fix this ? Thanks !

Comment: you need to import hashHistory from ReactRouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly mentions it. You did not define `hashHistory`.  so import it from react-router as

```
let hashHistory = Router.hashHistory;
```

All imports

```
let Router = window.ReactRouter;
let RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
let Route = Router.Route;
let DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
let hashHistory = Router.hashHistory;
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think it would be this simple

Comment: Exactly, sometimes things are simple only, overthinking makes then complicated. Anyways happy to help :)